# Sizing of a generation affects throughput of other generation in garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How the impacting of resizing of a generation size (say younger generation) affect the   collection frequency and pause times of other generations (say tenured generation)?

In this article https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html  , it is approximated to no effect. I want to understand the reason behind this approximation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to consider here is that the primary factors that control GC pause times are the rate of object allocation and how quickly those objects become garbage.

It's also important to understand that (in Hotspot) young and old generations use different algorithms.

For the young generation, collection is simply copying objects to a survivor space or tenuring into the old generation.  How big the old gen. is will only have an impact if there isn't enough space to promote all the necessary objects.

For the old gen., there are different algorithms but they all need to identify live data and usable space.  Changing the size of the young generation will affect how frequently a minor GC happens but not how much data ultimately ends up in the old gen.  Depending on the algorithm used, it may be necessary to perform a full compacting collection but, again, when this happens will not be affected by the size of the young gen.  The rate of tenuring and fragmentation of the old gen. will be the deciding factors.